# Java get bean value

Tags: java, properties, javabeans, apache-commons, getter

Given the following:

```
public class Person {
    private Car car;
    // .. bean stuff
}
```

.

```
public class Car {
    private CarStuff carStuff;
    // .. bean stuff
}
```

I can use BeanUtils to set the "car" property of Person:

```
BeanUtils.setProperty(person, "car", theirCar);
```

Ok that was super easy. Now how do I get "car" out by its name?

```
BeanUtils.getProperty(person, "car")
```

Will return a String, but Car is not a String

I have tried:

```
Map<String, ? extends Object> props = new HashMap<>();
BeanUtils.populate(person, props);
```

but there is no "car" entry, and investigating the documentation, the output (while promisingly of type Object) would still be either String or String[]

My classes all have proper bean getter and setter methods. How can I obtain the value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using [`PropertyUtils.getProperty(Object, String)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#getProperty(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)) instead

Comment: I took the liberty to add a link to your answer